# How to use the content of the kill-ring as the prefix-arg for universal-argument?

Tags: emacs, arguments, argument-passing

Sometimes I want to be able to do the following:

"C-u xxx ..."

where xxx is the integer which I did last put into the kill-ring (by killing a number in my buffer).

It's something I'd like to use with a macro so I can't enter that integer manually.

So how can I pop the kill ring and (parse and) pass the number that was popped to "C-u"?

Note that I want to use this with several functions, so I really want this to be working just like C-u is (but instead of manually having to enter the number, I want to it to be fetched from the kill ring).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rough stab at doing that:

```
(defun prefix-argument-from-kill-ring ()
  "Set the numeric argument for the following command to the
number that was the previous kill."
  (interactive)
  (setq prefix-arg (list (string-to-number (current-kill 0)))))
```

A more principled implementation would inspect the text of the kill and do something sensible if it were not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Using `digit-argument` as a template, I wrote this, which seems to work well enough:

```
(defun yank-universal-digits (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((digits (current-kill 0))
         (digits (if (string-match "\\`0*\\([1-9][0-9]*\\)\\'" digits)
                     (match-string 1 digits)
                   (error "Current kill is not a positive integer")))
         (num (string-to-number digits)))
    (cond ((integerp arg)
           (setq prefix-arg (+ (* arg (expt 10 (length digits)))
                               (* num (if (< arg 0) -1 +1)))))
          ((eq arg '-)
           (setq prefix-arg (- num)))
          (t
           (setq prefix-arg num)))
    (setq universal-argument-num-events (length (this-command-keys)))
    (save&set-overriding-map universal-argument-map)))

(define-key universal-argument-map [?\C-y] 'yank-universal-digits)
```

Arranging for the killed digits to appear in the minibuffer just as if you had typed them directly is left as an exercise.

Comment: +1 to you too! Now to be honest when I looked at the code of *digit-argument* inside *simple.el* (I think) I felt lost and came here on SO to ask how this should be done. Can you explain a bit how your solution differs from the one *gsg* (besides the integer check) gave?

Comment: It's largely the same as `digit-argument`, except that that function handles a single digit (stored in a variable called `digit`) whereas mine handles a possibly multi-digit number, which I store in the variable `num`.  Since `num` may be larger than 10, I need to multiply the existing prefix by ten to the power of the number of digits (that's the `(expt 10 (length digits))` expression), rather than always simply 10 as in `digit-argument`.